# Backtracking in recursive predicates

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

Assume we have the following predicates (This is an example from [Programming in Prolog](http://www.springer.com/computer/swe/book/978-3-540-00678-7)):

```
[F0] isInteger(0).
[F1] isInteger(X):- isInteger(Y), X is Y+1.
```

1. The first result for query isInteger(R), the marker is placed at F0, and will return R=0
2. If user presses ; , the marker is placed at F1, we move to subgoal(isInteger(Y), which is satisfied with F0) and R=1.

I understand the above. Now here are my questions:

1. If user presses ; again, where is the marker? How does the search proceed to return R=2? I have tried to understand the images in page 78-79 of the book, but it is not clear to me. The online tutorials that I found, do not handle backtracking in presence of recursion.

I am looking for any tutorials that explain backtracking in presence of recursion, hopefully with images of stack contents that helps me understand.

Thank you in advance
Suzanne

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Understanding backtracking and recursion by using images works for very tiny examples, but it does not scale to larger programs. Also, by stepping through a program you easily miss the most interesting properties. Fortunately, there are better notions than that. Let's take your example `isInteger/1`.

### Set of solutions/answers

Your primary interest is to ensure that you are describing the right thing. Here, the second rule is most interesting. Read it in the direction of the arrow `:-`. That is, right-to-left: Provided `Y` is an integer, and `X is Y+1` then also `X` is an integer.

Then, you can estimate the set of solutions which is infinite in this case.

### Termination properties

The next question concerns the termination properties of the predicate. Note, that it cannot – in fact **must not** – terminate, if it has to produce infinitely many answers. On the other hand, ground queries like `isInteger(1)` have either one or no solution. So it is desirable that the predicate terminates for such cases. However, your definition does not terminate here!

### Failure slices

To better understand this, I will use a [failure-slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failure-slice). That is, I will insert goals **`false`** into your program. If the resulting program fragment does not terminate, then the original doesn't.

```
?- isInteger(1), false

isInteger(0) :- false.
isInteger(X) :-
   isInteger(Y), false,
   X is Y+1.
```

Only a very small part is responsible for non-termination! The remaining part does not even look at the value of `X` at all. Therefore your program terminates *never*. No matter how you call it.

See [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Tracing this in the [swish](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/) console:

```
% Handover to indenting predicate

isInteger(X) :- isInteger(X,0).

% As isInteger(), with printouts

isInteger(0,I) :- ws(I), format('0 reached\n').
isInteger(X,I) :- wrout('>', X,Y,I), ID is I+1, isInteger(Y,ID), wrout('<', X,Y,I), X is Y+1, wsucc(I).

% Writing out

wrout(C,X,Y,I) :-ws(I),format('~a X=',C),write(X),format(',Y='),write(Y),format('\n').

% Writing "success"

wsucc(I) :- ws(I),format('success\n').

% Indenting by 2*N underscores

ws(0).
ws(N) :- N>0, format('__'), ND is N-1, ws(ND).
```

Check whether 2 is an integer via `? - isInteger(2).` (but do not call Next for this or an never-ending search will occur!)

```
> X=2,Y=_G5707
__0 reached
< X=2,Y=0
__> X=_G5707,Y=_G6473
____0 reached
__< X=_G5707,Y=0
__success
< X=2,Y=1
success
true
```

Enumerate integers using `?- isInteger(I)`

```
0 reached
I = 0
```

"Next"

```
> X=_G5328,Y=_G5926
__0 reached
< X=_G5328,Y=0
success
I = 1
```

"Next" (note that we restart at indentation '__')

```
__> X=_G5926,Y=_G391
____0 reached
__< X=_G289,Y=0
__success
< X=_G257,Y=1
success
I = 2
```

"Next" (note that we restart at indentation '____')

```
____> X=_G391,Y=_G3260
______0 reached
____< X=_G391,Y=0
____success
__< X=_G289,Y=1
__success
< X=_G257,Y=2
success
I = 3
```

Very nice.

I am going to explain this to the local team. Here is an illustration of the integer enumeration process with some "original notation". Hopefully self-explanatory.

[image: integer enumeration backtracking illustration]

Comment: The program you call correct cannot be used to enumerate natural numbers.

Comment: @false Excellent point! Clearly I am mistaken. I need to think more about this.