# How does is_integer(X) procedure work?

Tags: recursion, prolog

I read in Mellish, Clocksin book about Prolog and got to this:

```
is_integer(0).

is_integer(X) :- is_integer(Y), X is Y + 1.
```

with the query `?- is_integer(X).` the zero output is easy but how does it get 1, 2, 3, 4...

I know it is not easy to explain writing only but I will appreciate any attempt.

After the 1-st result `X=0` I hit `;` then the query becomes `is_integer(0)` or is still `is_integer(X)`?

It's long time I search for a good explanation to this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prolog uses "backtracking". After it gives you the solution `X=0` and you hit `;`, it will move on to `is_integer(X)` because it's already done `is_integer(0)`. When it calls `is_integer(X)` as a clause, then the recursive call to `is_integer(Y)` will go back to `is_integer(0)` sine it's a new call. You can turn on `trace.` in your prolog interpreter and watch what happens. :)

Comment: Yes I did watch it with the trace but it doesn't arrive to me. Look how I see it: 1) The query gets matched with the fact and X = 0.

Comment: When you hit the second `;`, backtracking takes you to the last choice point, which would be the last call to `is_integer(Y)` which had first instantiated `Y=0`. The next time it will instantiate `Y=1` for the same reason your first `;` instantiated `X=1`. The calls nest deeper and deeper to give you `2`, `3`, etc...

Comment: how does Y get = to 1? From my view is_integer(Y) gets always matched to is_integer(0) and Y always = 0. Sorry for being stupid.

Comment: backtracking to the last choice point. See Daniel Lyons' detailed explanation.

Comment: Have you realized that this example is a bit flawed, in the sense that when called with an instantiated argument, you get a true, and upon backtracking end up in an endless loop?

Comment: Please look at this response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115722/backtracking-in-recursive-predicates/14116016#14116016

Answer (score 4):

This strikes to the heart of what makes Prolog so interesting and difficult. You're definitely not stupid, it's just *extremely* different.

There are two rules here. The existence of alternatives causes choice points to be created. You can think of the choice point as a moment when Prolog saw an alternate way of proceeding with the computation. Prolog always tries rules in the order they appear in the database, which will correspond to the order they appear in the source file. So when you issue the query `is_integer(X)`, the first rule matches and unifies X with 0. This is your first result.

When you press ';' you are telling Prolog to fail, that this answer is not acceptable, which triggers backtracking. The only thing for Prolog to do is try entering the other rule, which begins `is_integer(Y)`. Y is a new variable; it may or may not wind up instantiated to the same value as X, so far you haven't seen any reason why that wouldn't be the case.

This call, `is_integer(Y)` essentially duplicates the computation that's been attempted so far. It will enter the first rule, `is_integer(0)` and try that. This rule will succeed, Y will be unified with 0 and then X will be unified with Y+1, and the rule will exit having unified X with 1.

When you press ';' again, Prolog will back up to the nearest choice point. This time, the nearest choice point is the call `is_integer(Y)` within the second rule for `is_integer/1`. So the depth of the call stack is greater, but we haven't left the second rule. Indeed, each subsequent result will be had by backtracking from the first to the second rule at this location in the previous location's activation of the second rule. I doubt very seriously a verbal explanation like the preceeding is going to help, so please look at this trashy ASCII art of how the call tree is evolving like this:

```
1     2       2
     /         \
    1           2
               /
              1

^     ^        ^
|     |        |
0     |        |
     1+0       |
             1+(1+0)
```

where the numbers are indicating which rule is activated and the level is indicating the depth of the call stack. The next several steps will evolve like this:

```
2            2
 \            \
  2            2
   \            \
    2            2
   /              \
  1                2
                  /
                 1

   ^             ^
   |             |
1+(1+(1+0))      |
 = 3          1+(1+(1+(1+0)))
                = 4
```

Notice that we always produce a value by increasing the stack depth by 1 and reaching the first rule.

Comment: Daniel reading it again after some time I realize your answer is superlative. But I am still stocked at this problem. Why would the depth of the call increase at each backtrack? I mean why backtracking would turn the rule in one like new? And what makes the connection betwin the different leveles?

Comment: @vincent Please email me, and I'll continue the explanation. It won't fit in a comment.  :)  fusion@storytotell.org

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Daniel is very good, I just want to offer another way to look at it.

Take this trivial Prolog definition of natural numbers based on TNT (so 0 is `0`, 1 is `s(0)`, 2 is `s(s(0))` etc):

```
n(0).            % (1)
n(s(N)) :- n(N). % (2)
```

The declarative meaning is very clear. (1) says that 0 is a number. (2) says that `s(N)` is a number if `N` is a number. When called with a free variable:

```
?- n(X).
```

it gives you the expected `X = 0` (from (1)), then looks at (2), and goes into a "new" invocation of `n/1`. In this new invocation, (1) succeeds, the recursive call to `n/1` succeeds, and (2) succeeds with `X = s(0)`. Then it looks at (2) of the new invocation, and so on, and so on.

This works by unification in the head of the second clause. Nothing stops you, however, from saying:

```
n_(0).
n_(S) :- n_(N), S = s(N).
```

This simply delays the unification of `S` with `s(N)` until after `n_(N)` is evaluated. As nothing happens between evaluating `n_(N)` and the unification, the result, when called with a free variable, is identical.

Do you see how this is isomorphic to your `is_integer/1` predicate?

**A word of warning.** As pointed out in the comments, this query:

```
?- n_(0).
```

as well as the corresponding

```
?- is_integer(0).
```

have the annoying property of not terminating (you can call them with any natural number, not only 0). This is because after the first clause has been reached recursively, and the call succeeds, the second clause still gets evaluated. At that point you are "past" the end-of-recursion of the first clause.

`n/1` defined above does not suffer from this, as Prolog can recognize by looking at the two clause heads that only one of them can succeed (in other words, the two clauses are mutually exclusive).

Comment: `n_/1` now does never terminate, whereas `n/1` does when there are finitely many solutions

Comment: @false You are of course correct, but the demonstrated `is_integer/1` has the exact same problem.... Unfortunately I don't have the book to see the context of the example. Do you know why it is presented like this?

Comment: It only shows once again, that beginners should not use `(is)/2`. Instead, `library(clpfd)` should be used.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it seeing your part Boris. The Y goal gets instantiated with the head of the rule and gets the previous value of X and in the second goal of the rule increments the X by 1. I am very close to being sure. Maybe I didn't realize that backtracking is made from buttom to top? Any way all of you are very kind to help me.

Comment: @vincent Backtracking goes to the last choice point created, and predicate clauses are evaluated top to bottom, so yes.

Comment: +1, very good, declarative answer. And I second *false*'s suggestion that beginners should use `library(clpfd)` instead, where `X in inf..sup` states that `X` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I attempted to put into a graphic @daniel's great answer. I found his answer enlightening and could not have figured out what was going on here without his help. I hope that this image helps someone the way that @daniel's answer helped me!